Techniques For Optimisation Over LOCC Measurements
Consider that I have a quantity that I want to calculate, but it involves optimizing over LOCC protocols $\mathcal{P}$. Although the set of LOCC operations is convex, it seems complicated to characterize it because of the involvement of arbitrary rounds of classical communication; that is, measurement strategies happening at a given round depend on measurement outcomes that have occurred in all the previous rounds and the not-so-well understood separation between SEP and LOCC (that SEP can distinguish a set of states that LOCC cannot). Quantities like entanglement cost and entanglement distillation very much depend on the minimization and maximization over all LOCC protocols, $\mathcal{P}$, possible, so given the importance of these entanglement measures, I thought there would be methods to tackle the problem of optimization over LOCC protocols, but looks like I was wrong.
I've gone through many papers, and it seems like almost all approaches to these problems are not straightforward and actually quite non-linear and peculiar. Some standard methods I've come across to tackle these involve extending the set of LOCC to SEP or PPT, which are well characterized, so given this, one can then "possibly" convert the given problem to a semi-definite optimization program to find solutions for situations involving optimization over SEP/PPT operations and then, if lucky, somehow magically come up with a LOCC protocol that reaches those solutions.
The quantity under question that I wish to calculate is accessible information $I_{acc}$, but the measurements (done on an ensemble, $\mathcal{E}$, to extract classical information) are restricted to only LOCC-type measurements (call this $I_{acc}^{LOCC}$). Typically, if one considers global operations, then for an ensemble $\mathcal{E} \equiv \{p_i; \rho_i\}$, the Holevo Quantity $\chi = H(\rho_{\mathcal{E}}) - \sum_i p_i H(\rho_i)$ upper bounds $I_{acc}$ and the usefulness of Holevo Bound is that it can be asymptotically saturated. For $I_{acc}^{LOCC}$, it seems like the closest I could find is from these papers: Locally Accessible Information: How Much Can the Parties Gain by Cooperating? and associated papers that cite it. The problem is the "Holevo-like" bound they find cannot be asymptotically saturated and is greater than even the Holevo Bound in some cases, practically making it useless in those situations.
Given these, is there a way to approach such a problem, not just for $I_{acc}^{LOCC}$ but in general for any problem involving optimisation over LOCC protocols?
